How can i get the advertising of a Ble device during scanForDevices (flutter_reactive_ble)?
I'm developing a cross-platform application (Windows & Mobile). I'm trying to get the advertising data of some BLE devices during the scan process. With Win_ble (a library that I'm using for the Windows part), I've managed to do this, and this is what I see in the console:
flutter: Received Message : {_type: scanResult, bluetoothAddress: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:00, rssi: -61, timestamp: 25006552342029.465, advType: ConnectableUndirected, localName: Ble_device, adStructures: [{type: 1, data: [6]}, {type: 3, data: [15, 24]}, {type: 171, data: [160]}, {type: 9, data: [75, 69, 68, 95, 65, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52]}], serviceUuids: [{0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}]}.

The adStructures are what I'm searching for also with Flutter Reactive BLE, but I haven't been successful. Here is the code I'm using:
when i do this:
_scanStream = _flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: <Uuid>[]).listen((event) {
  if (_filterName(event) && !_listId.contains(event.id)) {
    _listId.add(event.id);
    print(event);
    ...
  }
});

in the console i get this
I/flutter ( 7088): DiscoveredDevice(id: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00, name: Ble_device, serviceData: {}, serviceUuids: [0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], manufacturerData: [], rssi: -59, connectable: Connectable.available)

How can I retrieve the adStructures (the advertising of a ble device) using Flutter Reactive BLE?

There is a now closed issue that might be related. Someone asked how to retrieve the raw advertisement data. But as you can read in the issue, the stated that they want the behaviour of the library to be the same on all platforms. Since you can't access this info on iOS you can't get it though flutter_reactive_ble. The are also more (in my eyes) related issues: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/610 and https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/216
